# Anybody know the O notation for this algorithm? I think it might be exponential but not entirely sure

Tags: python, big-o

Anybody know the O notation for this algorithm? I think it might be exponential but not entirely sure.

```
def test(n):
   sum = 0
   for i in range(0, n//2, 2):
        for j in range(0, n//3, 3):
            sum += n

   return sum
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with the test function?

Comment: Why would it be exponential? Seems completely quadratic to me.

Comment: `sum += n` is executed O(n^2) times; to be exponential, you would basically need integer addition itself to be exponential.

Answer (score 1):

For the first loop `n/2` numbers are seen, and for each such number, `n/3` numbers are seen. So `O((n/3)*(n/2))`, which is equal to `O(n^2)`.